# Feature Request- adding "date tags"

Tags: support, feature-request

There are many questions that have never been answered as they have been stomped on by newer questions. There are also questions where the user has got an answer but it didn't work for him.

My solution to this is date tags. There would be 5 specific date-tags under the unanswered questions:

[This-Month]
[This-Year]
[1-3 years]
[4+ years]

I would also enjoy an `unaccepted` filter, like we have with unanswered.

We would be able to sort questions out with these tags. It would put an end to all the old unfinished questions.

Of course, we wouldn't sort out the date-tags with normal tags; Instead we could have them lying on the side of a question. However, the main purpose of these tags is to have them on the preview questions page, and so that we can search with them.

Comment: Already a mechanic to only list unanswered questions.

Comment: See search help: http://superuser.com/help/searching.  You can do date range searches and filter for unaccepted.

Comment: :( I was never told anything about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search feature already has built-in mechanisms to find such questions.

Dates can be specified in relative form (e.g., 1y, 3m), and can be used to filter both the question's creation date (with the `created:` directive) and  its last activity date (with the `lastactive:` directive).

The `hasaccepted:` directive can filter question according to whether or not they have an accepted answer.

So, for example, if you want to search all the [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) questions that don't have an accepted answer and created within the last three years, you could use [`[linux] hasaccepted:0 created:3y`](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+created%3A3y).

You can find additional information about searching in the [How do I search?](https://superuser.com/help/searching) page in the Help Center.